# Create an image consisting of boxes in 2 colours using python

Tags: python, arrays, user-interface, tkinter

I have an array

```
arr = [[1,0,0,1], 
       [1,1,1,1], 
       [1,1,1,0]]
```

I want to create an image that makes a green box where there is a 1 and a red box where there is a 0

P.S. I do not want to make a plot, but an image.

Using Tkinter, I am getting all the boxes in a single row, but I need it to be arranged in rows and columns like in the 2D array. 
In my code, I am not able to figure how to move to a new line after printing the boxes corresponding to a row

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
arr = [[1,0,0,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,0]]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        if arr[i][j]==0:
            w = tk.Label(root, text="red", bg="red", fg="white")
            w.pack(padx=5, pady=10)
        elif arr[i][j]==1:
            w = tk.Label(root, text="green", bg="green", fg="black")
            w.pack(padx=5, pady=20)
        w.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    # need something here to move to a new line after printing each row
tk.mainloop()
```

Current Output : 
[image]

Comment: with `pack()` you would have to create separated `Frame` for every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Tkinter grid() Method:**
>
> The Grid geometry manager puts the widgets in a 2-dimensional table.
>   The master widget is split into a number of rows and columns, and each
>   “cell” in the resulting table can hold a widget.

use the grid method to tell the manager in which row and column to place them. You don’t have to specify the size of the grid beforehand; the manager automatically determines that from the widgets in it.

```
root = tk.Tk()
arr = [[1,0,0,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,0]]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        if arr[i][j]==0:
            w = tk.Label(root, text="red", bg="red", fg="white").grid(row=i, column=j)
        elif arr[i][j]==1:
            w = tk.Label(root, text="green", bg="green", fg="black").grid(row=i, column=j)
tk.mainloop()
```

result:

[image]

> Note that the widgets are **centered in their cells.** You can use the
>   **sticky** option to change this; this option takes one or more values from the set N, S, E, W.

example:To align the labels to the left border, you could use W (west)

in your case:

```
w = tk.Label(root, text="red", bg="red", fg="white").grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=(W, E))
```

result:

[image]

Comment: This worked pretty well for me using the sticky option. 

I am now trying to save the image created inside the canvas (this grid of green and red boxes). Tried using postscript function, but doesnt seem to work. Any ideas ?

Comment: u can use: from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.grid()` layout manager

```
for i in range(len(arr)): #rows in arr
    for j in range(len(arr[i])): #cols in that row
        if arr[i][j]==0:
            w = tk.Label(root, text="red", bg="red", fg="white")
        elif arr[i][j]==1:
            w = tk.Label(root, text="green", bg="green", fg="black")
        w.grid(row = i, col = j)
```

This puts your label in a "2-Dimensional Table" consisting of rows and columns.
There is also `padx` and `pady` for padding
 Comment if something can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`grid()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) layout instead of `pack()`, you can also use `place()` layout but in that you've to do a lot of work. Also the size of the labels will be different and will not fill the whole cell of a grid, to do that use `sticky = 'nsew'`, this will stretch the `Label` to fill the cell.

**Here is the code**

I used `enumerate()` function it returns the index of the of the array.

If you want to have all label's object then you can create a list or dictionary to access each of them separately. For example create a `list` in the beginning and do `list.append(L)` in the loop to each `Label` for future reference.

```
import tkinter as tk

arr = [[1,0,0,1], 
       [1,1,1,1], 
       [1,1,1,0]]

root = tk.Tk()

for row , ar in enumerate(arr):
    for col, color in enumerate(ar):
        bg = 'green' if color else 'red'
        fg = 'black' if color else 'white'
        L = tk.Label(root, text=bg, bg=bg, fg=fg)
        L.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='nswe')

root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]